# Finding different values on a grouped dataframe based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am trying to write a function which creates a dataframe first and groups it by a cloumn.
Function takes  line_count and distance as arguments.
Here is the dataframe :

```
hit_count = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start_Index','Start','Stop_Index','Stop','Hit_Count'])
```

I grouped the dataframe based on Hit_Count:

```
hit_count = hit_count.sort_values(by='Hit_Count', ascending=False)
```

And to make operations on the dataframe I convert each column into numpy arrays except Hit_Count:

```
Start_Index = np.array(hit_count['Start_Index'])
Stop_Index = np.array(hit_count['Stop_Index'])
Start = np.array(hit_count['Start'])
Stop = np.array(hit_count['Stop'])
```

Dataframe goes like this:

```
       Start_Index      Start   Stop_Index   Stop   Hit_Count
    9044    1         0.00374      68     0.00376     14
    9047    1         0.00374      68     0.00376     14
    9055    1         0.00376      68     0.00376     14
    9052    1         0.00376      68     0.00376     14
   16999    2         0.00376      68     0.00376     13
   16996    2         0.00376      68     0.00376     13
    8668    1         0.00376      44     0.00376     13
    ...     ...        ...         ...      ...      ...
   24610    3         0.00378      48     0.00377     9
   56602    7         0.00396      73     0.00396     9
   24618    3         0.00377      48     0.00377     9
  634334    86        0.00462     473     0.00477     9
```

That is very big dataframe. The function should find the start indexes and stop indexes which has most hit counts. It will draw lines from start indexes to stop indexes. There can be multiple lines, so line count is an argument also. But as you can see at top rows some Start indexes and stop indexes are same or very close. If function draws of first 3 or 4 lines as requested in argument named line_count those lines will be same or very similar.
That's what I am trying to prevent.
So I added distance as argument.

```
liner = []
liner.append(0)
for m in range(line_count-1):
    for i in range(len(hit_count['Hit_Count'])):
      for j in range(len(liner)):
        if (Start_Index[liner[j]] - distance < Start_Index[i] < Start_Index[liner[j]] + distance) or (Stop_Index[liner[j]] - distance < Stop_Index[i] < Stop_Index[liner[j]] + distance):
          pass
        else:
          if j == len(liner) - 1:
            liner.append(i)
            break 
      if len(liner) == (line_count):
        break
```

First row of dataframe is good to draw always, so I crated a list named liner and add 0 into it. This list will contain dataframe's chosen iloc indexes. Function will draw lines which is added to liner list. After adding first line of hit_count dataframe (0), it goes to down and searches for other values and next value's start and stop indexes should be as far to previous ones at least as distance. Every indexes should be considered in liner list. That's why the `for j in range(len(liner)):` part. And if new value's indexes are far as requested to all liner values it can be added to list. It is this part: `if j == len(liner) - 1: liner.append(i) break` 
But still it finds similar lines. After last try I asked the indexes:

```
for i in range(len(liner)):
    print('Start Index:', hit_count['Start_Index'].iloc[liner[i]])
    print('Stop Index:', hit_count['Stop_Index'].iloc[liner[i]])
```

And:

```
Start Index: 1
Stop Index: 68
Start Index: 75
Stop Index: 473
Start Index: 16
Stop Index: 64
Start Index: 76
Stop Index: 473
Start Index: 16
Stop Index: 65
```

As you see some stop indexes are same (473) and thirth line starts at 16 and stops at 64, and last line starts at 16 and finishes at 65.

I hope I was able to tell the problem. Is there anyone who can make suggestion to prevent similar lines?
Sorry for the long question and aprreciate for any help. Thanks